# Platform Encryption in dev org

Tags: platform-encryption, developer-org

I turned on Platform Encryption in a Dev Org.  I have one user who can Manage Encryption Keys and View Encrypted Data and another who cannot.

Why can my user who cannot view encrypted data still view and edit data in encrypted fields (like Contact.FirstName and a field I added called Super_secret_secret__c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry @CharlesKoppelman, I hope it's better this way

Essentially view encrypted data is unrelated to shield encryption. Whether the user can read and/or edit the data from your custom object is subject to the regular rules (CRUD and FLS). If you want to prevent the user from reading and/or editing this field, please leverage FLS instead as you would do with other custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely correct.

**Manage Encryption Keys** and **View Encrypted Data** permissions do not restrict users editing the encrypted fields. Users can edit the field values though they cannot view the data.

Refer [Classic Encryption for Custom Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm&type=0)

> Encrypted fields are editable regardless of whether the user has the “View Encrypted Data” permission. Use validation rules, field-level security settings, or page layout settings to prevent users from editing encrypted fields.

Comment: Op says the user can still view the data

Comment: Just to elaborate a little bit, the view encrypted data used to be applicable to shield, hence maybe the confusion, but we are sun setting this behavior for shield, this user permission only applies to the classic encryption:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_security_pe_ved_decouple_announcement.htm

The manage encryption keys do apply to Shield though, but this is a setup permission for controlling who can manage the keys themselves, such as creating or rotating keys

Comment: Yes, both users can view and edit all data.  This does not answer my question.

Comment: @AlexandreHersans Can you explain why both users can view data in all fields and if I have control of that?

Comment: Essentially view encrypted data is unrelated to shield encryption. 

Whether the user can read and/or edit the data from your custom object is subject to the regular rules (CRUD and FLS).

If you want to prevent the user from reading and/or editing this field, please leverage FLS instead as you would do with other custom fields.

Comment: @AlexandreHersans I would love if you could post this all as an answer instead of a comment on someone else's answer. I would accept your answer.